# AddEventlistner, getting object reference to the clicked button

Tags: c#, event-handling, unity-game-engine

I'm adding eventlisteners to some buttons in a foreach loop in Unity 5.3.

```
 foreach (Button btn in buttons)
 {
    btn.onClick.AddListener(() => levelBtnClicked());
 }
```

How can i get a button reference to the button that is clicked? So I can check the properties of the button in the levelBtnClicked function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `levelBtnClicked` function take `Button` as parameter then **pass** in each `Button` instance to parameter during loop.

```
Button[] buttons;

void Start()
{
    foreach (Button btn in buttons)
    {
        btn.onClick.AddListener(() => levelBtnClicked(btn));
    }
}

void levelBtnClicked(Button buttonClicked)
{
buttonClicked.image = ......
buttonClicked.name....
Debug.Log("Button Clicked: "+buttonClicked.name);
}
```

Comment: That was the first thing i tried but didnt work. But i figured it out. Simple change the foreach loop to a for loop. 
Thanks though :)

Comment: No problem. Didn't try this, but you sure that didn't work?

Comment: Yes, tried it. Not really sure why it didnt work... But when i changed to using a for loop it somehow worked :p

Comment: @JørgenAndersen Ok. Glad you got it working. One correction for your code. Remove   `Button btn = buttons[i];` It is unnecessary. Replace `btn.onClick.AddListener(() => levelBtnClicked(btn));` with  `btn.onClick.AddListener(() => levelBtnClicked(buttons[i]));`

Comment: Also replace `buttons.Length-1` with `buttons.Length`.